# ASP.NET MVC videos, podcasts, YouTube links, audios, resources, articles?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, video, asp.net-3.5

Can anyone suggest where can I find good starter videos for [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) (other than ASP.NET site)?

Any noteworthy resources and articles will also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dimecasts?

[http://dimecasts.net](http://dimecasts.net/Casts/ByTag/MVC)

...you can also filter by Casts Level (Beginner, Intermmediate, Advanced) but then you'll have to search through to find the ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply justin. it was really fast.

Comment: Dimecasts is a very good site, but I find their MVC videos are not for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few at this site: http://video.google.com/videosearch?q=asp.net+mvc ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start with the **NerdDinner** project:

[Creating NerdDinner.com with Microsoft ASP.NET Model View Controller (MVC)](http://videos.visitmix.com/MIX09/T49F)

No slides. Just code. Start with File|New and build a real Web site with ASP.NET, ASP.NET AJAX, Authentication, Authorization, MVC, Microsoft SQL Server and jQuery in sixty-five minutes or less. By Scott Hanselman

Answer (score 0):

[ASP.NET has a massive resource on it](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/), with Rob Conery's Storefront also on there.

Comment: leaving asp.net(it was mentioned in the question)

Comment: Sorry - should of read the question more closely.  However it is the best resource I have found, and there are a lot of videos on it.

Answer (score 0):

Best Tech Videos is a user driven social content website dedicated to finding the best educational videos for developers. You can search there for ASP and .Net tagged videos. I'm not sure if you will find something that match your interests, but try it, is a great resource center to learn if you can't afford attend all the valuable IT conferences and events. The url is http://www.bestechvideos.com/